# interpolation question. From MyMaxScore free AP BC Calculus exam.

Tags: calculus, interpolation

First, I disagree with the answer sheet.  That is why I am posting this question here.

The question: Part B, Question 3a.

[image: MyMaxScore Free AP BC Calculus Practice Exam]

[image: Question 3a]

The answer given (Sorry for the picture being so small).

[image: The answer given from the practice exam.]

I know that math is wrong.  $\frac{804-1291}{9-7.5} = -324.\bar6$

I still don't like the answer given, because the time to be estimated is 5pm, which is closer to 4:30pm rather than 6pm.  Wouldn't the answer be closer to the value for 4:30pm rather than 6pm?

Comment: What really is the question? You posted the description of the problem, but I can't decipher what do we really need to find? Do we need to find the rate at which the number of people was changing at 5:00 PM?

Comment: @AneeshDogra thanks, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to assume the function is piecewise-linear although it is only constrained to be twice-differentiable.  It is the rate of change which is being asked for, so if it is piecewise-linear, any time between 4:30 and 6:00 would have the same value (it is negative because the number of people signing in is decreasing between 4:30 and 6:00).  But according to the way the question is worded, any value is possible, because for example a polynomial (all are twice-differentiable) can be made to fit.

Comment: So if one just wanted to take the average of the end points of the piece containing 5pm.  the answer should be -324.667. I still don't understand how did they get an answer shown in the answer sheet (-258).

Comment: It is an error.  The numerator is 387 but it should be 487.